# Glassfish deploying EAR Cannot create broker instance. A broker instance is already created

Tags: amazon-ec2, glassfish, jms, multicast, ear

Full Logs: 
https://pastebin.com/kMR6AiZH

```
[2017-04-23T11:08:51.428+0000] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle] [tid: _ThreadID=209 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(11)] [timeMillis: 1492945731428] [levelValue: 800] [[
      SJSMQ LifecycleManagedBroker configuration=
        brokerInstanceName       =imqbroker
        brokerBindAddress        =null
        brokerPort               =47630
        brokerHomeDir            =/opt/payara-4.1/mq
        brokerLibDir             =/opt/payara-4.1/mq/lib
        brokerVarDir             =/opt/payara-4.1/glassfish/domains/payara_personal_domain/imq
        brokerJavaDir            =/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.29.amzn1.x86_64/jre
        brokerArgs               =null
        MasterBroker             =null
        brokerId                 =null
        adminUsername            =admin
        adminPassword            =<default>
        adminPassFile            =null
        ConnectionURL            =
        dbType                   =null
        dbProps                  ={}
        dsProps                  ={}
        useJNDIRmiServiceURL     =true
        useSSLJMXConnector       =true
        brokerEnableHA           =false
        clusterId                =null
        rmiRegistryPort          =47730
        startRmiRegistry         =true
        brokerStartTimeout       =  jmxServiceURL            =null
    60000
    ]]

    [2017-04-23T11:08:51.428+0000] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=209 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(11)] [timeMillis: 1492945731428] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Cannot create broker instance.  A broker instance is already created.
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.runtime.impl.BrokerInstanceImpl.createInstance(BrokerInstanceImpl.java:137)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.runtime.impl.ClientRuntimeImpl.createBrokerInstance(ClientRuntimeImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.blc.EmbeddedBrokerRunner.createTheInVMBrokerInstance(EmbeddedBrokerRunner.java:291)
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.blc.EmbeddedBrokerRunner.<init>(EmbeddedBrokerRunner.java:130)
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.blc.LifecycleManagedBroker.start(LifecycleManagedBroker.java:452)
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter.start(ResourceAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter$1.run(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:553)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.startResourceAdapter(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:544)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveOutboundResourceAdapter.init(ActiveOutboundResourceAdapter.java:130)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ActiveInboundResourceAdapterImpl.init(ActiveInboundResourceAdapterImpl.java:90)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.instantiateActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:141)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveRAFactory.createActiveResourceAdapter(ActiveRAFactory.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.createActiveResourceAdapter(ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.java:210)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.createActiveResourceAdapter(ResourceAdapterAdminServiceImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.createActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorRuntime.java:405)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorService.loadDeferredResourceAdapter(ConnectorService.java:184)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.loadDeferredResourceAdapter(ConnectorRuntime.java:1331)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.getActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:315)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:166)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:314)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execut]]
```

It seems to be related to JMS. I have the exact same config running on my dev machine without issues. This is on an EC2.

The only 'solution' I found was https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/863 where the suggestion is to disable JMS. But I need it.
Reason: AWS (and other cloud providers) as well as other networks do not allow multicast.

All I want is the default JMS adapter. This is not running in a cluster, just a single host. Is it possible without multicast?

My server is payara, essentially glassfish.

Comment: I think this might just be a misconfiguration. If you start Payara Server, an embedded MQ broker will start with it on port 7676, fully managed by Payara Server. Are you trying to do any other configuration? You shouldn't need to add any extra resource adaptor or anything.

Comment: I haven't added any resource adapters

Comment: How have you configured your project? Are you sure you haven't packed up any broker JAR in your EAR which Payara is trying to deploy and start, for instance?

Comment: Well I copied the ear from the netbeans dist folder. It runs on both a windows and Linux dev machine when deployed through netbeans

Comment: @Mike it seems that it may not be configured correctly, I just tested a clean set up on a VM and the same errors appeared. Is it OK to copy the ear as I did?

Comment: Should be - that's helpful, though, we can say that it's not related to the github issue or multicast. You could try checking in your EAR lib folder to see if there's any jar that starts with "imq". If so, they don't need to be there, all the mq jars you need are provided by Payara.

Comment: There is nothing in the lib other that my mysql-connector jar

Comment: @mike I solved it I just manually reapplied all my configuration to the default domain and it worked... Thanks